# How can a simple bounce animation be applied to a StackPanel on UserControlLoad?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I am very new to Silverlight and Silverlight animations. I have a StackPanel. When the user control loads I want the stack panel to slide into view from the bottom of the screen). A huge bonus would be to make it bounce off the top of the screen once it hits the top. I am looking iinto the Silverlight Toolkit and the TransitioningContentControl but I am not sure this will work.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you learn using Expression Blend since that simplifies tremendously what you are trying to do.

For a basic read up on animations I recommend an article by Lawrence Moroney:
[Create Animations with XAML and Expression Blend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc721608.aspx#id0410105)

The link goes to a section talking about triggers and the last code examples shows how to activate something on page load.

Any other questions on basic animations using XAML would hopefully be found in the rest of the article.